# Background service when app is not open or closed

Tags: android, android-service, locationmanager, android-gps

I have a location service that add/updates data in firestore. It is working fine when the app is open, but if I force close the app or switch to another app, the service is no longer working. Im testing this on Realme 3 pro device.

1. Run service even if app is closed in app manager.

**Service Class**

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "SERVICE";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 0;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation.set(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    LocationInitialize();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

}

public void LocationInitialize(){
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
    broadcastIntent.setClass(this, RestartService.class);
    this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved( Intent rootIntent ) {
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
    broadcastIntent.setClass(this, RestartService.class);
    this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
}
```

**Broadcast Receive**

```
public class RestartService extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, LocationService.class));
    } else {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, LocationService.class));
    }
}
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<receiver
        android:name=".service.RestartService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="restartservice" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".service.LocationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: Its been a long time Since the background restrictions applied on android . Service can not run in background infinitely . You need to use a Foreground Service for it . Also read [Background Location Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits).

Comment: better you can go for workmanager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to google developer recent policy you shouldnt be using
> manifest based broadcast receivers , though it will not work above 26
> SDK

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#changes-system-broadcasts

So no need to use broadcast receiver to restart service.

**Use this code to restart service**

Updated service class

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "SERVICE";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 0;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation.set(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    LocationInitialize();
    return START_STICKY;
}

  @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();      
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startMyOwnForeground();
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "1");
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("My service.")
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .build();
            startForeground(1, notification);
        }
    }

  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground() {
        String channelName = "My service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel("2", channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "2");
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My service")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }

public void LocationInitialize(){
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    // no need to do anything here
    //Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    //broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
    //broadcastIntent.setClass(this, RestartService.class);
    //this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
        restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

        PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
                restartServicePendingIntent);

        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Service stops if I remove app from recent apps.

Comment: Which device are you using ?

Comment: Okay the problem was I did add background service in manifest.

Comment: Is there a way to only show the ongoing notification if the app is minimized or removed from recent apps?

Comment: i am glad it worked and dont forget to upvote my answer for others